# Using JGoodies for my application

Tags: java, eclipse, jgoodies

I want to use JGoodies for my java application so I downloaded the necessary libraries and put them in the CLASSPATH:
[image]

But I can't use the components of JGoodies such `JGSplitButton` and `JGTextField` and eclipse don't know it:
[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: usually eclipse know that and do the imports automatically, but this time it didn't and I did the import myself but still the same error.

Comment: As this is likely to be a problem with your IDE, add `eclipse` as tag.

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924736/how-to-use-classes-in-referenced-libraries-in-eclipse or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148195/how-to-use-a-class-from-jar-in-eclipse

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman sry I thought it's not eclipse problem, I thought I forget some libraries or something that's why I didn't add eclipse as tag, and thnx for the links but they didn't help.